# Why is r adding \n at the end of factors in column?

Tags: r

R is adding \n at the end of some character values after importing the data (it only does this for some, not all). It doesn't show up when I look at the dataset from the environment, but when I get the names of the factors (R stored them as factors) by just typing the name of the column in the console the \n shows up in the console.  This is a problem because R won't recognize the factor levels unless I add \n at the end.  I haven't been able to find anything about this in SO, does anyone know how to get rid of it?

Note: One of the levels has special character (&) but \n doesn't show up in that case.  I've tried to find a commonality for when it does show up, but it seems pretty random.

I am using read.csv to read the data.

`dat<- read.csv("datapath.csv", header=TRUE,strip.white=TRUE)`

I use `levels(datcol)`, and it shows something like this:

`> levels(datcol)
[1] "All"                  "BMUS & CREMUS"        "BMUS\n"

[4] "CREMUS All"           "CREMUS Crustaceans\n" "CREMUS Fishes\n"

[7] "Precious Corals\n"`

I've tried adding `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` into the read.csv, and 
then `dat$datcol<- gsub("/n", "", dat$datcol)`, but \n is still showing up.

The data looks something like this:

`Grp1Code   datcol     hYear        B
1           BMUS        1966        130
1           BMUS        1967        167
1           BMUS        1968        164`

Comment: I think its most likely an issue with how you're reading in the data. For example, some of your data could have line breaks in it.

Comment: Need more clarification. Can you post what the data looks like and how is it being read in? What function are you using to read it ?

Comment: @h.a: I used write.csv to read my data, I also added what the factor levels come out as in the console and what my data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/n` means a line break. The data you are reading in probably has line breaks in it. Depending on what function you are using to read in the data, you might add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, and then:

`df$problemColumn <- gsub("\n", "", df$problemColumn)`

might work.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex P. I just tried that but unfortunately nothing happened :/

Comment: my bad, i had the wrong slash (i had `/n`, i've changed it to `\n`

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, this solution worked well also included

```
df$problemColumn <- gsub(" ", "", df$problemColumn)
```

to remove any unwanted spaces

Comment: Hi BBmanNZ, welcome to SO. While this solution works, it does not solve the OP's issue and results in _all_ spaces being removed. SO is a great resource because answers are supposed to be tailored to the specifics of the question. Using `x <- "test string\n with linebreak"`, compare `gsub(" ", "", x)` with `gsub("\n", "", x)`.  This is important as there may be other functions downstream that require the values to retain their original form. Thanks